# Laravel uni-directional hasOne saves related object as JSON

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Assuming I have the following class:

```
class Town extends Eloquent {

    public function mayor()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Person');
    }
}
```

How is it that `$town->push()` gets tricked into thinking that it has mayor column?

```
$town = new Town();
$town->name = "Some Town";
$town->area = 124;

$mayor = new Person();
$mayor->first_name = "Ricardo";
$mayor->last_name = "Miguelito";
$mayor->birthdate = Carbon::createFromDate(1950, 7, 14);
$mayor->gender = Person::MALE;

$town->mayor = $mayor;
$town->push();

$this->assertGreaterThan(0, $town->mayor->id);
```

Here's the output:  (I just removed the backticks from the columns)
    `Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column    'mayor' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into towns (name, area, mayor, updated_at, created_at) values (Some Town, 124, {"first_name":"Ricardo","last_name":"Miguelito","birthdate":"1950-07-14 17:51:02","gender":"male"}, 2014-12-13 17:51:02, 2014-12-13 17:51:02))`

Comment: Can you show us the `Person` model please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### tldr;

**1. You need to save parent model first, then child model**

**2. push doesn't create a relation, only saves already existing (and loaded) related models**

---

Also, Eloquent relations don't work this way:

```
$town->mayor = $mayor;
```

All it does is saving `$mayor` model as `$town`s attribute. It's never treated as a relation in this case.

So here is what you need:

```
$town = new Town();
// do what you need with town
$town->save();

$mayor = new Person();
// do what you need with mayor

$town->mayor()->save($mayor); 
// this associates mayor with town and saves it, it's equal to:

// if town relation is defined on mayor model:
$mayor->town()->associate($town); 
// otherwise:
$mayor->town_id = $town->id;

// then
$mayor->save();
```

Just a note: All you are testing here, is Eloquent, which you don't need.

Comment: Thank you!  Yes Laravel noob here :D

`$town->mayor()->save($mayor);` does work properly, but I was actually testing the push() method of models to see if it can do some magic, but oh well.